# UDP multicasting with IPAddress.Any

Tags: c#, sockets, multicast

Good day all

I am going through the MSDN website try to familiarize mystelf with Multicasting and how it works. I'm wondering: when does one use the

> IPAddress.Any

it refers to a commented out line from [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.multicastoption(v=vs.110).aspx) link

> //IPAddress localIP = IPAddress.Any;

I have seen it on multiple occasions, but what does IPAddress.Any really mean?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: What's the question about the update?

Answer (score 2):

A quick googling reveals:

[What's IPAddress.Any - MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/5600b0b7-466c-42d9-a177-a76c5e23664c/whats-ipaddressany?forum=wcf):

> IPAddress.Any will listen on any IP Addresses assigned to the PC. For
>   example, if I am connected to the network via wireless and wired,
>   there would be two IP Addresses assigned. This means that I would
>   listen for requests on both IP Addresses. If I would take the IP of
>   say the wired then I could only receive requests from that NIC.

As you can see, this is for specifying an address to listen on ([effectively, an equivalent to `IPAddress.Parse("0.0.0.0")`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipaddress.any.aspx)) and thus is not specific to multicasting. See [How to do a UDP multicast across the local network in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767215/how-to-do-a-udp-multicast-across-the-local-network-in-c) for an example of the latter's implementation.

Comment: that is why I am asking